# In Cannot be resolved and MasterMind

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Ok, I am having a problem receiving a value... I have been researching for several days, but nothing has hit the topic I need.  It is a mastermind game.  I am creating this for a Final project in my High School programming class.  The Eclipse Compiler is telling me that in cannot be resolved.  How do I fix this and Accomplish my goal.  This is not being run in an applet.

```
package masterMind;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MasterMind {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is MasterMind, a logic game");
        System.out.println("To win you must guess correctly where each number is");
        System.out.println("You will be told if you get one correct");
        System.out.println("You will only get 10 tries, then you lose");
        System.out.println("Lets begin");

        //Change this value to change the game
                int m1=2;
                int m2 =3;
                int m3=2;
                int m4=1;
        //Create Board
        System.out.println("__ __ __ __");

        Scanner UserGuess = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();
```

I have very limited Coding knowledge, so please keep it simple and explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.in is the InputStream of the system (like the cmd for windows) , in order to read from that you use the Scanner or InputStreamReader just like you are trying to do ... so instead of

```
in.nextInt();
```

you need

```
userGuess.nextInt();
```

and btw learn to use capital letters properly as it will help you later , like userGuess should not start with a capital since its an instance not a class.

anyways , for your game you have to guess 10 times which means you have to repeat the same guessing action 10 times or till the user guesses all the numbers , thats when you should use a while loop like so  ....

```
 boolean guessedAll = false;
 int guessedCount=0;
 int tryCounter=0;
 while(tryCounter<9 || !guessedAll){
//read the number from the user and test it ...
//if number equals one of the numbers above then guessedCount++ ...
//if guessedCount==4 then guessedAll=true 
 tryCounter++;
}
```

now i almost gave you all of the algorithm needed to do that homework , but i ain't going to solve it for you till you try , else you will learn nothing ;)
you could ofcourse ask for help as comment after you've tried some ... good luck

Comment: How do i get the compiler to read their answer? How would I tell the users if they had gotten a guess right?

Comment: just like everyone else hinted ... int guess = userGuess.nextInt()

Answer (score 1):

for `nextInt` method you  should call it from `Scanner` object

Change this

```
int num = in.nextInt();
```

To

```
int num = UserGuess.nextInt();
```

Comment: That seemed to work, I will continue to expand and finish the program.  I will tell you if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You never closed the brackets when you started the class nor when you started the main method. Match every `{` with a `}`.

```
package masterMind;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MasterMind {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This is MasterMind, a logic game");
    System.out.println("To win you must guess correctly where each number is");
    System.out.println("You will be told if you get one correct");
    System.out.println("You will only get 10 tries, then you lose");
    System.out.println("Lets begin");

    //Change this value to change the game
            int m1=2;
            int m2 =3;
            int m3=2;
            int m4=1;
    //Create Board By randomly generating the number

    //After generating the code, print the blank board to start the game
    System.out.println("__ __ __ __");

    //Take in the user's guess (limit is 10)
    int limit = 10
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        Scanner UserGuess = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();
    //Other logic..Leaving it for you to attempt


    }
}
```

You want to make a program which the user must guess where each number is in a 4 digit code.. Well how do you do this?

We need the user to be able to input a number, typically the rules of this game are:

1. There are 6 possible numbers or colors
2. The code is 4 numbers or colors long
3. The user has ten tries to guess the code correctly

That means we have to start by doing something like this.

1. Generate the 4-digit code somehow (with the possible combinations from 0000-6666) and the split the random number put it in an array
2. Ask the user to enter a number guess along with a position for that number
3. Keep checking the user guess against the code, each time display the current guesses and which ones they have correct

Comment: I have not gotten into how to create arrays... I did a small amount of this during javascript but never went into a lot of detail...

Comment: The following is a tutorial from oracle that explains the creation of arrays in Java and should help you out quite a bit with your program's initial setup. If you need more help, I will be here monitoring the question and trying my best to assist. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html